# What are the benefits and drawbacks of using 2 or more CSS Framework?

Tags: design, css, bootstrap

I have experience in Bootstrap, Foundation, and Sematic UI.

On my next application, I am planning to use

- Bootstrap for Grid
- Foundation for Menu & Side nav
- Semantic UI for Forms, icons, etc.

Initially, I experienced the issue with styles on button/tables etc. As all the framework have the definition of `button` and `table` tag.

Is it good or bad? Give your suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

I just build a site using Skeleton CSS for this grid, and bootstrap for the responsive menu. As long as you can manage overwrites or remove unnecessary style with ease it shouldn't be an issue. This sped up my production time as I wasn't noodling around in frameworks trying to create custom elements from an inarticulate framework.